# Evaluate a Python one-line statement in GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, python

I'm using `run-python` on GNU Emacs 24.3 for its "Inferior python shell" and am trying to get behavior similar to `lisp-send-last-sexp`, that sends and evaluates an expression in the running interpreter. I'm only trying to do this for one line at a time.

I shortened the solutions [given here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/3s98uTafg6E) to the following function:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          'my-python-send-statement)

(defun my-python-send-statement ()
  (interactive)
  (local-set-key [S-return] 'my-python-send-statement)
  (end-of-line)
  (set-mark (line-beginning-position))
  (call-interactively 'python-shell-send-region))
```

It works, halfway. When I run this command down several lines, I get a string of several >>> prompts and I can't figure out why, as only one line should be sent. Also, sometimes the result won't be shown immediately, and I have to run the command twice. For example:

9+9  # run the command on line 13 of .py file,

======

`# result in Python shell.`

`>>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> >>> 18`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER*: the following is self advertisement...

For managing interaction between a buffer and a code interpreter, I developed [`isend-mode`](https://github.com/ffevotte/isend-mode.el).

Here is how you'd use it:

1. Run a python interpreter in a terminal :

   <kbd>M-x</kbd>`ansi-term`<kbd>RET</kbd>`/usr/bin/python`<kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Switch to the buffer containing your python code :

   <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>`my-buffer.py`<kbd>RET</kbd>
3. Associate it with your terminal :

   <kbd>M-x</kbd>`isend`<kbd>RET</kbd>`*ansi-term*`<kbd>RET</kbd>
4. Type <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to send the current buffer line to the interpreter.

The advantage of `isend-mode` (from my perspective, at least) is that it is language-agnostic. You can use it in the same way for python, shell, or whatever interpreted language which you like.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after browsing the python-shell functions a bit more I put together a hack that solves my problem: send a print command after sending the region! For whatever reason this suppresses all the >>> prompts.

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          'my-python-send-statement)

(defun my-python-send-statement ()
  (interactive)
  (local-set-key [S-return] 'my-python-send-statement)
  (end-of-line)
  (set-mark (line-beginning-position))
  (call-interactively 'python-shell-send-region)
  (python-shell-send-string "; print()"))
```